# Spring Integration JDBC Outbound Channel Adapter using DSL

Tags: spring-integration

Is there a way to specify a JDBC Outbound Channel Adapter using DSL?

e.g.

```
<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter
            query="insert into foos (id, status, name) values (:headers[id], 0, :payload[foo])"
            data-source="dataSource"
            channel="input"/>
```

Also is it possible to handle parameters which may be null (e.g. if a field is null, substitute an empty string value).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According `<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter>` description:

```
 <xsd:documentation>
            Configures a Consumer Endpoint for the
            'org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcMessageHandler' for updating a
            database.
        </xsd:documentation>
```

we have `JdbcMessageHandler` which can be used as:

```
@Bean
public MessageHandler jdbcMessageHandler() {
    JdbcMessageHandler handler = new JdbcMessageHandler(this.dataSource,
       "insert into foos (id, status, name) values (:headers[id], 0, :payload[foo])");
    return handler;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow jdbcFlow() {
      ...
      .handle(jdbcMessageHandler())
      ...
}
```

The `null -> empty string` is possible via custom `SqlParameterSourceFactory`.

Comment: Thanks Artem, this gives me more flexibility to customise the insert. Cheers.